# Expected value of first duplication by sampling elements with replacement

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, random

Let $G$ be a group of order $m$. I am sampling elements $a_1, a_2, \ldots$ from $G$ with replacement - random and evenly distributed. The question is, when will there be the first duplicate, i.e. the minimum $j$ for which there exists a $i < j$ with $a_i = a_j$.

I thought of it in the following way: The probability of having a duplicate in the $k$-th run is

$$\frac{m}{m} \frac{m-1}{m} \cdots \frac{m-k+2}{m} \frac{k-1}{m} = \frac{m! \cdot (k-1)}{(m-k+1)! \cdot m^k}$$

that means "$k-1$ times no duplicate and a duplicate in the $k$-th run, so the expected value of samples before a match appears is

$$\sum_{k=1}^{m+1} (k-1) \frac{m! \cdot (k-1)}{(m-k+1)! \cdot m^k}.$$

[Here](https://maths-people.anu.edu.au/%7Ebrent/pd/rpb231.pdf), in theorem 2.2 it is stated that the expected number of evaluations before a match appears is $\sqrt{\pi m/2}$.

Checking the result with $m = 50$ gives me $\approx 8.54$ using my formula (see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20%28k-1%29%20*%20m%21%20*%20%28k-1%29%20%2F%20%28%28m-k%2B1%29%21%20*%20m%5Ek%29%20from%20k%20%3D%201%20to%20m%2B1%20when%20m%20%3D%2050)) and $5\sqrt{\pi} \approx 8.86$ using the formula from the article. Why is there a difference resp. where is the mistake I (?) made?